# Rot13 and the use of the modulo

Tags: python, string, modulo, rot13

I've been reading "Think Python" by Allen B. Downey and there's an exercise (8.12) in it where the author asks to create a ROT13 function. I did mine and it partially worked because I was struggling with the uppercases.

Here's a part of the solution provided by the author:

```
def rotate_letter(letter, n):
"""Rotates a letter by n places.  Does not change other chars.

letter: single-letter string
n: int

Returns: single-letter string
"""
if letter.isupper():
    start = ord('A')
elif letter.islower():
    start = ord('a')
else:
    return letter

c = ord(letter) - start
i = (c + n) % 26 + start
return chr(i)
```

The use of the modulo here makes the function work for the uppercases but I can't figure why !
It's clear that by using it we restart at the beginning of the ASCII values for uppercase but I can't figure the mechanism behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try breaking it down into steps, and printing out the intermediate numbers. Or, better, running it in an [online visualizer](http://goo.gl/k35Wjz).

With, say, the letter `'Q'` and the number 13, you'll end up with:

```
'Q'.isupper() is true
start = ord('A') = 65
c = ord('Q') - start = 81 - 65 = 16
i = (c + n) % 26 + start = (16 + 13) % 26 + 65 = 29 % 26 + 65 = 3 + 65 = 68
chr(i) is 'D'
```

As you can see, the magic part is that `(16 + 13) % 26`. So let's try running that on every one of the numbers from 0 (for `A`) to 25 (for `Z`) and see what happens:

```
>>> for i in range(26):
...     print ((i + 13) % 26),
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Adding, then taking the remainder with 26, means that when you get to 26 you go back around to 0. Just like adding 1 hour to 23:00 gets you to 00:00 on a clock (or, if you're an American, adding 1 hour to 12:00 gets you to 1:00).

Comment: `n=13` is a special case where you do not need to do `c = ord(letter) - start`. For `n=13` the rotation is just implemented as `return ord(letter) % 26 + ord('A')`.

Answer (score 2):

The modulo 26 has nothing to do with uppercase and lowercase per se, it's needed to make the sequence wrap back to the beginning.

Consider a simple "rot 1": treat the letters of the alphabet as numbers from 1 to 26, and add 1. If the input is 'a', you take 1+1=2 and get 'b'; if the input is 'z', you take 26+1=27 - but there's no 27th letter of the alphabet! So you calculate 27 mod 26 = 1, which "rotates" back to 'a'.

The actual trick for upper and lowercase in the implementation above is the definition of `start`, which turns ASCII positions into numbers 1 to 26 before applying the rotation, then turns the result back using the same offset.

Comment: I think it's actually 0 to 25, but it comes to basically the same thing.

Comment: Yes, it is 0 to 25. I've never understood why they teach modulo as "clock arithmetic" in America, where clocks go from 1 to 12 so it just confuses people, but don't call it that in other countries, where clocks go from 0 to 23 and it would work perfectly…